# Render a <h:inputText> when user enter a key on another input

Tags: javascript, ajax, jsf

I´m trying to render a input when the user type a key in another input.. i can do this when the user lost the focus of the first input but not when he´s typing yet.. somebody knows how do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can, by providing a specified event in the `event` attribute of `<f:ajax>`:

```
<h:inputText ... >
    <f:ajax render="input2" event="keydown" />
</h:inputText>
<h:inputText id="input2" ... />
```

It allows to fire an ajax call on `keydown` event instead of a standard `change` event and update the other text input.